# An interface, with a property that has a varying interface

Tags: angular, typescript, web, ecmascript-6

First, a link to my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnfgcx

I have written a more technical description of my issue in stackblitz aswell, so please read that for any clarification :)

So the title might be a bit confusing, but let me try to elaborate.

I have a basic interface for my "items", that has 2 properties:

id - a unique identifier 
item - a varying type (Either CarInterface or HouseInterface)

However, when I try to access properties of a CarInterface or HouseInterface, the type isn't recognized.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I suggest you take some more code from the live example and place it in the question. But I tried to give some insight in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `listOfCars` is typed as `ItemInterface[]`, which has the following definition:

```
export interface ItemInterface {
  id: number;
  item: CarInterface | HouseInterface;
}
```

TypeScript only knows that `item` will be either `CarInterface` or `HouseInterface`, but doesn't know which. So you'd have to cast:

```
const value = this.listOfCars.find(entry => (<CarInterface>entry.item).color === 'green');
```

This design seems a little odd though. It doesn't look like you need to mix cars and houses in the same list or anything like that, so typing them as the same may not be necessary. Are you sure you don't perhaps need a generic interface? Something like:

```
export interface ItemInterface<T> {
  id: number;
  item: T;
} 

public listOfCars: ItemInterface<CarInterface>[] = [];
```

Or perhaps an `ItemInterface` which the other interfaces extend?

```
export interface ItemInterface {
  id: number;
} 

export interface CarInterface extends ItemInterface {
  color: string;
  doors: number;
} 

export interface HouseInterface extends ItemInterface {
  rooms: number;
  squareMeters: number;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the very insightful reply :)

Using cast was what I was trying myself, but I wasn't sure how to approach it, this really helped!

I've seen generic interfaces, but haven't actually used it myself before, so I should definitely try to look into that, thanks!

My idea was to aim for something like your last suggestion, but I used `implements` instead of `extends`  , so I will probably try that approach

Comment: You're welcome. `extends` is used when creating a new interface that inherits properties from another. `implements` is used when creating a class that implements an interface.

Comment: So I tried using extended interfaces, but I ran into some trouble.

In the stackblitz I have a service. This service has a function, that is responsible for adding an item to an array, and returning that array. This function has return type "ItemInterface[]".
When I invoke the function from app.component:
`this.listOfCars = this.utilService.addItem(car, listOfCars) `,
I get the following error on `this.listOfCars`
`Type 'ItemInterface[]' is not assignable to type 'CarInterface[]'.`
Is there a way to make addItem generic, so that it can return any of the 2 types of lists? Or

Comment: The method expects items, and a car is not an item, so no you can't do that. You're expecting the method to add a car to an array of items? If you could do that, there's no point in having type safety. You should pass the method an item, whose `item` property is a car. Or change the method to except cars or houses.

Comment: If you want a truly generic method, you could have the signature be `public addItem<T>(itemToAdd: T, arrayTarget: T[]): T[] { ... }`, but that still wouldn't make your error go away because you're trying to force one type into an array of another type that's not compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply once again :) I have messed around with it all day, and I ended up with a solution with a generic approach, and it works like a charm!

I feel like the quality of my code has been raised by 200% :D Thanks again for the tips, even after I gave you credit